# Unable to load from csv to mysql table?

Tags: mysql, csv

```
 LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'hr.csv' INTO TABLE hr_analytics  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '`' IGNORE 1 LINES(NO,SATISFACTION_LEVEL,LAST_EVALUATION,NUMBER_PROJECT,AVERAGE_MONTLY_HOURS,TIME_SPEND_COMPANY,WORK_ACCIDENT,LEFT,PROMOTION_LAST_5YEARS,SALES,SALARY)
```

when i run above query i get:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'LEFT,PROMOTION_LAST_5YEARS,SALES,SALARY)' at line 1

how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that `LEFT` is a MySQL key word. Try this:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'hr.csv' INTO TABLE hr_analytics  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '`' IGNORE 1 LINES(`NO`,`SATISFACTION_LEVEL`,`LAST_EVALUATION`,`NUMBER_PROJECT`,`AVERAGE_MONTLY_HOURS`,`TIME_SPEND_COMPANY`,`WORK_ACCIDENT`,`LEFT`,`PROMOTION_LAST_5YEARS`,`SALES`,`SALARY`)
```

Comment: i  have already ran the query and i got com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'NO' in 'field list'

Comment: Please post the table definition and the first 2 or 3 lines (anonymized!) of the CSV!

Comment: Try using different quotes in lines as the identifier quote character is the backtick. Otherwise MySQL "thinks" that you point to a columns. Try this : LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'hr.csv' INTO TABLE hr_analytics  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '`' IGNORE 1 LINES('NO','SATISFACTION_LEVEL','LAST_EVALUATION','NUMBER_PROJECT','AVERAGE_MONTLY_HOURS','TIME_SPEND_COMPANY','WORK_ACCIDENT','LEFT','PROMOTION_LAST_5YEARS','SALES','SALARY')

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem because you use a reserved SQL word 'LEFT'.

> If an identifier contains special characters or is a reserved word,
>   you must quote it whenever you refer to it.

The identifier quote character is the backtick "`".

Comment: 1LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'hr.csv' INTO TABLE hr_analytics  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '`' IGNORE 1 LINES(`NO`,`SATISFACTION_LEVEL`,`LAST_EVALUATION`,`NUMBER_PROJECT`,`AVERAGE_MONTLY_HOURS`,`TIME_SPEND_COMPANY`,`WORK_ACCIDENT`,`LEFT`,`PROMOTION_LAST_5YEARS`,`SALES`,`SALARY`) `when i run the above query i get   **Unknown column 'NO' in 'field list'**